# My submitted data is stored in two rows of table rather than one

Tags: php, mysql, forms, row

Currently i am working on a project where i got two tables one is users table and other is movie table.
The problem is that when am submitting a form related to movie table it is storing data in two rows

1. One row contains data which i have previously tested by submitting form.
2. Second row contains data which i have currently tested by submitting form.

Am using localhost server for testing so am testing it by submitting different data each time and when the form is submitted it stores two rows in table one is previously tested and one is currently tested.

This is my code.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['fav'])) {
        $errors['fav'] = 'Favourite required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['rank'])) {
        $errors['rank'] = 'Rank required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['rewatched'])) {
        $errors['rewatched'] = 'Rewatched required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['status'])) {
        $errors['status'] = 'Status required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['recommend'])) {
        $errors['recommend'] = 'Recommend required';
    }

    $fav = $_POST['fav'];
    $rank = $_POST['rank'];
    $rewatched = $_POST['rewatched'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $recommend = $_POST['recommend'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    // Select id from users and insert into anime
    if (count($errors) === 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO anime SET movie_fav=?, movie_rank=?, movie_rewatch=?, movie_status=?, movie_rec=?, id =?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('siissi', $fav, $rank, $rewatched, $status, $recommend, $id);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if ($result) {
            $movie_id = $stmt->insert_id;
            $stmt->close();

            $_SESSION['fav'] = $fav;
            $_SESSION['rank'] = $rank;
            $_SESSION['rewatched'] = $rewatched;
            $_SESSION['status'] = $status;
            $_SESSION['recommend'] = $recommend;
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Details have been submitted successfully!';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'alert-success';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Database error: Could not update details";
        }
    }
}
```

Am using session_variable to get currently logged in user id. I can't understand where did i go wrong can you help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to post your table schema and shed more light on the situation

Comment: The script you have only makes one call to save to the database. There is no way it can save into two two rows

Comment: actually when i am refreshing my page it automatically stores previously submitted data in table. each time i refresh my page it stores data with one row

Comment: You're still in "POST" mode when you refresh the page (there should be a little browser popup warning you that information will be resent). To avoid, redirect to the "GET"/initial version of the page/form

Comment: @kerbholz thank you for your response . Yes as you say it shows popup box of info resending  Is it safe to use GET method ?

Comment: Don't change the `method` of your form to `GET`, if all your data is successfully saved, _redirect_ to the "initial" plain url of your form page, the url you use to first show your form. This way you won't get the "resend information" popup when refreshing

Comment: @kerbholz Ok i get it what you are suggesting if you don't think am asking too much can you tell me how can i do it

Comment: Once you checked that data has been successfully saved, just use `header('Location: myform.php')` to redirect to the page, replacing `myform.php` with your page name. More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @kerbholz actually i have tried your suggestion soon after your previous comment and it worked out fine so thank you very much @ kerbloz